i cant delete snapshot in VirtualBox
I can't delete the snapshot. I created an Ubuntu virtual machine, worked for a month and I need to transfer it to another virtual machine on the hypervisor. I converted it for the hypervisor and I see old files without the current vdi version of the virtual machine. VirtualBox does not display the snapshot in a separate menu, but it is displayed in the disk settings. When trying to delete a snapshot, it writes an error and cannot find the snapshot. Correction of the configuration file .vbox didn't help. After starting the VM, the lines that I deleted to unlink the snapshot reappear.
Tell me what to do to keep the current version.vdi and delete the snapshot?
snapshot
